# Security Error with Report Viewer Control and RDLC Reports in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Using ASP.NET 4.0, I'm creating an RDLC stream by instantiating a `Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel.Report`, setting the `Code` property, and returning the stream using the `RdlSerializer`.

Then I'm passing that stream to the ReportViewer like so:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(rdlcStream);
```

If I don't set the `Code` property, I don't get any errors and the report displays properly, but when I set the `Code` property for a report that needs custom code, I get the below mentioned `'RequestMinimum' is obsolete` error.

> An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘[BC40000] 'RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.'.’.

This error doesn't occur using the Report Viewer control in a winforms app.

Has anyone seen/resolved this issue?

Answer (score 7):

I do not know exactly the cause of this error, but in my experience, it was related with a simple copy and past from a expression from one cell to other cell inside the results table, all this after  making changes in the layout and groups.

I recommend you delete any expression or formula, verify that your report is executed without any error message, and rewrite down all the expressions and formulas one to one, checking in every formula that your report open correctly.

That worked for me.

Comment: +1 I had the same error when copying from SSRS rdl to local rdlc. I had to delete all expressions (keeping grouping, labels) and then recreate them. Not sure what exact statement it didn't like, but I've had this twice now and this is what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the page number in this line
    `<Value>=Globals!PageNumber + ' of ' + Globals!TotalPages</Value>`
When removed everything goes right and i don't know why

Comment: <Value>=Globals!PageNumber + " of " + Globals!TotalPages</Value>
Use double quotes, not single quote.  Just fixed this one.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for those got this error and generate report markup.

Likely one of you  `<Value>` tags starts with `"="` sign and if this is not an expression you need to use `EvaluationMode="Constant"`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a copy and paste error for me. More exactly, I missed a space.

This expression caused the error:

```
=Fields!CompSalesName.Value& vbcrlf & Fields!Address.Value
```

While it should have been

```
=Fields!CompSalesName.Value & vbcrlf & Fields!Address.Value
```